# Auth0 + Ionic on android device

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, auth0, google-plus-signin

I am trying to add Google login in an Ionic app.
Sadly, Google remove the inappbrowser login flow, so I added the GooglePlus plugin which is working fine and I am able to get an id_token.

The issue is that I cannot use auth

> `.getProfile(idToken, funct...)`

This will return an 401 error saying that this token is not authorized; in the Auth doc is implies that the method can only be used with id_tokens acquired from Auth login.

My question is:
Is there a method to login to Auth using id_tokens, something like Firebase's "loginWithCredentials()"

Comment: I should point out I am not using Lock widget.